# Bootstrap menu not working on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap for a uni project but the menu (hamburger) doesn't do anything on Mobile. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: because that page doesn't have JS file. Please add Bootstrap JS file there!

Comment: Slowly learning - Thank you!